# Forcing installation of DirectAdmin on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: ssh, vps, ubuntu-14.04

Well, I was given a DirectAdmin license for my VPS at nearly no-cost, and so would like to give a try on it(as recommended from my friend). 

But now i got the setup file from 
http://www.directadmin.com/setup.sh
and resulting not having it installed due to the problem

```
*** 64-bit OS ***

This appears to be Debian version jessie/sid.
This version is essentially Debian 8, which is not released yet, so the install won't work
See this page for more information:
    http://www.debian.org/releases/
```

I need it desperately, so anyone who helps is much appreciated~

Comment: So you "would like to give it a try" AND you "need it desperately"? Why not install a supported Linux version, like Debian 7?

Comment: I would like to give it a try, and I'm in and always in a "when problem is not solved I would be mad" state. I don't even know DirectAdmin doesn't support Ubuntu 14.04.1, my VPS is not used only for DirectAdmin installing and don't even know that DirectAdmin exists at the time I'm installing Ubuntu 14.04.1. Thanks for noticing me though. ;D

Comment: Installing DirectAdmin has significant changes on your system configuration, so you might want to think twice before installing it on an existing system 'just to give it a try'. You might never be able to completely remove it, and it can break existing services. Supported Unixes are RedHat Enterprise / CentOS 5.x 32/64-bit, 6.x 32/64-bit, FreeBSD 8.x 64-bit, 9.x 32/64-bit, Debian 6.x 32/64-bit, 7.x 32/64-bit. If you just want to try it, I suggest you install it on a virtual machine.